# bash script – for i in {x..y}

Tags: bash, scripts, programming

i am writing a script in bash and I would like to give the two numbers in the brackets, x and y to be precise, as variables.

I wrote the script this way:

```
echo "x?"
read x
echo "y"
read y

for i in {$x..$y}
```

but it does not work.

How could I set it up to make it function?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: is `x` always lower than `y`? if it is, so just do `$i=$x` and do your loop with a`while [ $i -l $y ]`

Comment: Imo not a good solution, you need to check if `$x < $y`, then you need to assign the counter, then you need to increment. There are better methods I'd say.

Comment: Related or maybe duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/712990/631600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this simple `bash` solution:

```
for ((i=$x;i<=$y;i++))
```

---

**Before using the following functions, read below !**

For a sequence of numbers, you might use `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq $x $y)
```

If you really need brace expansion, you can use `eval`:

```
for i in $(eval echo {$x..$y})
```

**Disclaimer**:
**`eval` is evil.** This case is a perfect example: If the user writes `$(do_something_evil)` instead of a number, `do_something_evil` will be executed. So before using `eval`, make sure your input is not evil. **The same applies to `seq $x $y`.**

If you still want to use one of these functions, test the user input, which is generally a good idea: [How do I test if a variable is a number in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806923/7365127)

Comment: +1 for evil eval (did not mention it here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/). Sites giving "bad / incomplete" programming advice may lead to insecure code used in the wild!

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorry for my bad english
2. You can do this:

**In bash**

```
echo -n "x: "; read x
echo -n "y: "; read y
```

- "Like" for {$x..$y}

  ```
  for i in $(echo "echo {$x..$y}" | /bin/bash)
  do 
    echo $i
  done
  ```

  or shorter

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "echo {$x..$y}" | tr " " "\n"
  ```
- With awk

  ```
  echo "$x:$y" | awk -F ":" '{while($1<=$2){print $1; $1++}}'
  ```
- With xargs

  ```
  bash -c "echo {$x..$y}" | xargs --max-args=1  # or use -n instead --max-args. The same with parallel
  ```
- With parallel

  ```
  parallel -d " " --max-args=1 echo :::: <(bash -c "echo {$x..$y}" )
  ```

**In zsh**

```
for i in {$x..$y}
do
  echo $i
done
```

The result is almost the same in all cases.

In your code:

```
for i in {$x..$y}
```

Doesn't work because brace expansion has more precedence than variable expansion. You can read that in `man bash`.

I mean, `{$x..$y}` is not `{1..6}` expansion, or whatever, cause that supposes the contrary, i.e, that variable expansion has more precedence than brace expansion, then `$y` and `$x` does not expand then `{$x..$y}` neither, then it just prints "{1..6}" literally, i.e, first prints "{$x..$y}" and cannot make brace expansion because `$x` and `$y` are not integers, then expand the variables and prints "{1..6}".