# for loop doesn't work when "{0..$var}" is used

Tags: command-line, bash

Simple problem but I don't know how to fix it. Here's the code:

```bsh
missing_filters=('Sort key' 'Page' 'Pagesize' 'Sort direction')

for level in {0..$((${#missing_filters[@]}-1))}
do
    echo "${#missing_filters[$level]}^|^${missing_filters[$level]}"
done | column -tes "^"
```

It should show every element of the array with 1-4 before it like this:

```
1 | Sort key
2 | Page
3 | Pagesize
4 | Sort direction
```

However, I get the error `./advancedplexapi.sh: line 4608: {0..3}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..3}")`. I find this strange as the error shows exactly how I want the shell to interpret it (that being `{0..3}`). I did nothing wrong because otherwise the shell wouldn't give me the correct output in the error. Why doesn't it work? And ofcourse how can I fix this?

Comment: Ah I get it. It's just like the calculation order when doing math.

Answer (score 3):

It is not working as expected, because brace expansion is done before variable substitution.

You could use `seq` or a `for`-loop instead:

```
for level in $(seq 0 $((${#missing_filters[@]}-1))); ...
```

or

```
for (( level=0;level<="$((${#missing_filters[@]}-1))";level++ )); ...
```

For more details, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/712997/631600) to another question.

---

Also `"${#missing_filters[$level]}"` will not give `1 2 3 4`, but expand to the number of characters in each value --> `8 4 8 14`. Better use `$((level+1))`.

---

However, you could more easily loop the array keys:

```bsh
for k in "${!missing_filters[@]}"; do
    printf '%s | %s\n' "$((k+1))" "${missing_filters[$k]}"
done
```